# How to halt/pause other iframes if one iframe is already playing iframe source has externally hosted video?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have hosted my videos in bunny cdn for faster bandwidth, Now embedding 5 videos in a single HTML web page, The problem is I am unable halt/pause other iframes automatically if one iframe is already playing?iframe source has externally hosted video?

I have tried give the external link in video source tag but it's not working.
Can anyone quickly give me JS or Jquery to solve my problem

Comment: is `iframe source has externally hosted video?` a question? Only you know ... anyway, is iframe itself same or cross origin?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.